# Convert an array of numbers into key followed by indices which match the key

Tags: javascript

New to JavaScript. I am trying to convert an array of numbers

```
[ 12,14,12,10,11,10 ]
```

into an object array with the key as the number in the array followed by an array of indices where the number occurs such as

```
{'12': [0, 2]], '10': [3,5], '11': 4 }
```

I saw several examples with `reduce` but I don't understand how to create the array of items for a given key.

Comment: Does this answer your question? "[How can I group object keys based their value?](//stackoverflow.com/q/43683954/90527)", "[Swap key with value in object](//stackoverflow.com/q/23013573/90527)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) with an object as the accumulator.

The callback is given the previous accumulator, the current array element, and its index. We can initialize the property for the current element's value to an empty array if not already set with the [logical nullish assignment operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment) before adding the current index to that array.

```js
let arr = [ 12,14,12,10,11,10 ];
let res = arr.reduce((acc, curr, i)=>
    ((acc[curr] ??= []).push(i), acc), {});
console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{max-height:100%!important}
```

Comment: If the is single count then acc to OP's code it shouldn't be in an array

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation of the code. I ran the code snippet and it worked perfectly. For some reason the logical-nullish assignment did not work in google script. I also tried the examples from the MDN Web doc link and they  did not work either.

Comment: @sk65plus You can replace that with `(acc[curr] = acc[curr] || [])` for better support.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily achive the result using [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) in [for..of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop

```js
const arr = [12, 14, 12, 10, 11, 10];

const map = new Map();
arr.forEach((n, i) => (map.has(n) ? map.get(n).push(i) : map.set(n, [i])));

const result = {};
for (let [k, v] of map) {
  v.length === 1 ? (result[k] = v[0]) : (result[k] = v);
}

console.log(result);
```

```css
/* This is not a part of answer. It is just to give the output fill height. So IGNORE IT */
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```